# Android Studio , Activity Launcher result code -> Result Cancelled

Tags: java, android

Im currently learning android studio and messing around with multiple activities and passing data in between these activities.

The idea is in my main activity am using activity result launcher to launch the second activity and it'll receive data back and depending on the result code I do different things with it .

Before I did it in onAcitivityResult where this is how I handled results code if it was cancelled.

```
@Override
     public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data)
     {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            if (resultCode == DiceRoll.RESULT_OK)
            {
                TextView diceReturnResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.diceReturnText);
                int rolled = data.getIntExtra("rolled",-1);
                diceReturnResult.setText("Dice Result: You rolled " + rolled);
            }
            else if(resultCode == DiceRoll.RESULT_CANCELED)
            {
                TextView diceReturnResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.diceReturnText);
                int rolled = data.getIntExtra("rolled",-1);
                diceReturnResult.setText("Dice Result: You rolled " + rolled);
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Failed to recieve results from dice roll");
                diceReturnResult.setText("Dice Result: RESULT_CANCELED");
            }   
        }
    }
```

and so if I do receive result cancelled I can print it out saying that result cancelled

However now am trying to play around with activity launcher and I cant quite get the same thing to work not sure how I should approach this

```
    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                result -> {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == DiceRoll.RESULT_OK)
                    {
                        Intent data = result.getData();
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "recieved results from dice roll");
                    }
                    else if(result.getResultCode() == DiceRoll.RESULT_CANCELED)
                    {
                        TextView diceReturnResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.diceReturnText);
                        int rolled = result.getData().getIntExtra("rolled",-1);
                        diceReturnResult.setText("Dice Result: You rolled " + rolled);
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "Failed to recieve results from dice roll");
                        diceReturnResult.setText("Dice Result: RESULT_CANCELED");
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

and thats the activity launcher that I've done am im not sure how to print it out this time round?

Seeing that Intent data = result.getData(); works by just taking in the data I tried just doing
Intent data = "Dice Result: RESULT_CANCELLED" but I couldn't get it to work

and below is my onActivityResult method that I've changed to accommodate the Activity Launcher

```
@Override
     public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data)
     {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        TextView diceReturnResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.diceReturnText);
        int rolled = data.getIntExtra("rolled",-1);
        diceReturnResult.setText("Dice Result: You rolled " + rolled);

    }
```

Comment: Unclear what your problem is. Unclear why you posted three on activity results. Cannot get it to work is no good error description.

Comment: "multiple activities and passing data in between these activities" -- that approach has been obsolete for a while. Please consider using a single activity (or at least few, loosely coupled activities), with fragments or composables for your screens.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't doing everything you were doing in your `onActivityResult` in the `result` lambda? The whole point of the `StartActivityForResult` contract is to give you the same results as you got in `onActivityResult` without having to override that method.